# Keyword loosing rank when not having a Regional word in it

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, wordpress

This question has **nothing** to do with Improving my **Overall** Position on Search or my SEO
. I Very simply want to understand why **ONE** keyword in particular is Worse off on search under the Following Circumstance, Im not in search off a 100 ways to improve your search Posistion.

I want to know why:

The Keyword E.G

White Sock `Is doing Worse`
Then White Sock (**Region**)E.G `North America`

So Keywords are

1.**White sock**

2.**White sock Region**

Why does 2 do better then 1?

Comment: The Google algorithms are too complex and opaque to know for sure why rankings are exactly as they are in any particular case.   To get better SEO for some keyword, use the advice from [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

Comment: Losing is spelled l-o-s-i-n-g.